# How to give admin permission?

Tags: django, permissions, admin

So I have a User model that inherits from AbstractBaseUser

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from User.userManager import CustUserManager

    class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
        fname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = False)
        lname = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = False)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, db_index = True, blank = False,primary_key=True)
        course_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='DEFAULT VALUE')

        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        objects = CustUserManager()

        #Attributes for admin
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False, null = False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True, null = False)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, null = False)



        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            error = False
            try:
                User.clean_fields(self)
            except ValidationError as e:
                #print 'ValidationError: %s' %(e)
                error = True
            if error == False:
                super(User,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        def get_short_name():
            return self.fname
```

Then I have a an admin class

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from User.models import User

# Register your models here.
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('fname', 'lname', 'email')

    search_fields =['User__email']

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("search_users", "Can search"),)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Permission)
```

Now I first tried to have a search box show up on the admin page that would allow me to search through the my user t o find a particular one. When I go to my admin page, a search box never shows up. It says that I do not have any permission to edit anything, so is this the problem? If so , how to I add permissions to my admin? I have tried (as you can see in my code) to no prevail.

Comment: Are you logging in with the newly created user? If so, have you set `is_admin` to `True` before saving?

Comment: Yes,I handle that in user manager class

Answer (score 0):

Your app name and user model are both named `User`. This can cause Python to import wrong thing. Try renaming user model to `UserProfile` or something similar.